# qt project symbian os compatability problem?

Tags: c++, qt, symbian

hi i develop the nokia n97 application on nokia qt sdk but when i run the project on device it cause th os compatabiliy error 
so please help me which changes require in my qt project so it can run on my device.

Answer (score 1):

If you install the sis on the phone manually , it'll tell you what the exact error is .